# Python on Raspberry Pi: results are only integers

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am using the following python code on the Raspberry Pi to collect an audio signal and output the volume. I can't understand why my output is only integer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import alsaaudio as aa
import audioop

# Set up audio
data_in = aa.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NONBLOCK, 'hw:1')
data_in.setchannels(2)
data_in.setrate(44100)
data_in.setformat(aa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)

data_in.setperiodsize(256)

while True:
   # Read data from device
   l,data = data_in.read()
   if l:
      # catch frame error
      try:
         max_vol=audioop.max(data,2)
         scaled_vol = max_vol/4680      
         if scaled_vol==0:
            print "vol 0"
         else:
            print scaled_vol

      except audioop.error, e:
         if e.message !="not a whole number of frames":
            raise e
```

Also, I don't understand the syntax in this line:

```
l,data = data_in.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that it's reading in a byte. This line `l,data = data_in.read()` reads in a tuple (composed of `l` and `data`). Run the `type()` builtin function on those variables and see what you've got to work with.

Otherwise, look into the documentation for ***PCM Terminology and Concepts*** located within the documentation for the `pyalsaaudio` package, located [here](http://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/terminology.html).